# Unity3d файлы не записываются на телефон

Tags: c#, unity3d, text, файлы

Храню в файлах информацию и подгружаю ее в меню. Файлы хранил и в `Application.temporaryCachePath` и в `Application.persistentDataPath`. На компе все работало, при билде и запуске на андроиде файлов не оказалось!

Потом мне сказали что `temporaryCachePath` файлы временные, и поэтому может не работать, а в `persistentDataPath` - могут быть проблемы с доступом. Я воспользовался `TextAsset pathTxt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("LvlLocker", typeof(TextAsset));`  загрузкой ресурсов, опять же на компе работает, на андроиде файлы не оказывается. Подскажите как сделать на компе файл так, чтоб он был перенесен на андроид и я мог его спокойно прочитать. Сил нет, целый день не могу один файлик перенести на телефон и считать одну цифру!!

Comment: Перед переносом приложения на телефон проверьте манифест. Возможно в нем нет разрешения на доступ к файловой системе. Использую Application.persistentDataPath, но на winphone. Может быть дело с манифестом связано.

Comment: @nuts119 хотя в настройках плеера на Write Acces  было External SD, все же не нашел этого в манифесте, и дописал <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. Ничего не помогло. Но в настройках плеера в пункте Optimization - Preloaded Assets добавил свои файлы из папки Resources, и они начали переносится на телефон. С DataPath и CachePath проблема так и не решилась. Если генерирую файл прямо  в коде то все работает, а если просто хочу чтоб перенеслись с компа и в коде только читаю то не переносятся.

Answer (score 1):

Как я помню андроид, iOS, WP. Не могут читать файлы. Я в таком случае использовал реест через `Player.Prefs`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?